# Windows container transparent network: invalid CIDR address: /32

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to set up my container with the "transparent" network driver so that I can assign it with a static IP address in the same network as the container host.

Creating the network manually and running the container with the following commands works as expected.

```
docker network create -d transparent --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 --gateway=192.168.0.253 docker-network
docker run -it --name testContainer -P --network="docker-network" --ip 192.168.0.71 361758f74a1d powershell
```

However I'm using docker-compose to manage and run the container and this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: transparent
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.0.253
services:
  test-container:
    ...
    networks:
      docker-network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.71
    ...
    command: ping -t localhost > NUL
```

When I use docker compose to start the container I get the following error:

```
failed to create network containers_docker-network: Error response from daemon: invalid CIDR address: /32
```

I really don't understand the problem here. Not sure if it's a parsing error but I have tried to delete every IP address in the file and I really think the problem lies within this  `- subnet: 192.168.0.0/24`.

I have run the file into an YAML validator and it came out valid with no syntax erros.

I'm using a ping command to keep the container alive. I don't think this could be the culprit because the container doesn't even start but I'm keeping it here because its network related.

Any ideas on what could be the problem here? Thanks for your time!